# Display GridView Cell one by one after two seconds each

Tags: android

I want to display same image on each GridView Cell but each after on two to three seconds. Please try to help me. Thanks in advance

**PlayActivity.java**

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private Intent intent;
private GridView gridView;
private int rangeFrom, rangeTo, counter, imageId=R.drawable.horse;
private String order;
private String[] list;
private Handler handler;
private int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    intent=getIntent();
    if(intent.getStringExtra("rangeFrom")!=null && intent.getStringExtra("rangeTo")!=null)
    {
        rangeFrom=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("rangeFrom"));
        rangeTo=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("rangeTo"));
    }
    counter=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("counter"));
    order=intent.getStringExtra("order");


    Thread t1=new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                for(i= 1; i<=5; i++) {
                    gridView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
                    gridView.setAdapter(new PlayCustomAdapter(PlayActivity.this, i, imageId));
                    wait(2000);
                    gridView=null;
                    gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();

}
}
```

**PlayCustomAdapter.java**

```
public class PlayCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private int imageId, rangeTo;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public PlayCustomAdapter(PlayActivity playActivity, int rangeTo, int imageId) {
    context=playActivity;
    this.rangeTo=rangeTo;
    this.imageId=imageId;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rangeTo;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    ImageView iv;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowview;
    rowview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_gridview_list, null);
    holder.iv=(ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.iv.setImageResource(imageId);
    return rowview;
}
}
```

This is my code. And I want output like this.

[This is the output which I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wtqpy.jpg)

Comment: could you add required output?

Comment: @profesor79. Sorry but actually I am new in stackoverflow so I am not able to link image.

Comment: This is the output I want to achieve    https://www.dropbox.com/s/97vqjfvzl57czd5/photojoiner.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete working example of your requirement.

In **MainActivity.java**,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private GridView gridView;
    private ArrayList<Integer> imagesList;
    private PlayCustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        imagesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        adapter = new PlayCustomAdapter(imagesList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // By using AsyncTask
        new LoadImagesTask().execute();
    }

    private class PlayCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<Integer> imagesList;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public PlayCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> imagesList)
        {
            this.imagesList = imagesList;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return imagesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return imagesList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            ImageView iv;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Holder holder = new Holder();
            View rowview;
            rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_gridview_list, null);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.iv.setImageResource((int) getItem(position));
            return rowview;
        }
    }

    private class LoadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    // Here, I am getting launcher icon from resources.
                    publishProgress(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            imagesList.add(values[0]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In **activity_main.xml**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="esealed.com.testing123.MainActivity">
   <GridView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/gridView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In **play_gridview_list.xml**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me ᖷAЯAƸ but it is not working. Just showing white screen. That's it

Comment: I tried using dynamic linear layout but still I am not getting output.

Comment: @VirBhatt I have updated my answer with complete code.

Comment: Okay I marked. Sorry I don't know about this. Thanks for informing about this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

use post delay handler as

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowview;
    rowview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_gridview_list, null);
    holder.iv=(ImageView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(imageId);

        }
    },2000);
    return rowview;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nisar to help me. I try your code but in PlayActivity that for loop iterating first and after its condition will become false then it is calling PlayCustomAdapter and all images are displaying together. Not one by one.